# Plymouth not showing image at boot

Tags: boot, raspberrypi, plymouth

I've been working for a while now on getting Plymouth to show a custom logo at boot. The theme is loaded properly, and most things work fine. I've hit a little snag though which I can't figure out.

When the Pi4 boots, it'll show the plymouth splash screen, except that the image is missing. I can manually fix this by hitting `esc` twice, then the image shows just fine.

`/var/log/syslog` doesn't contain any clues as to why this is happening, same for `/var/log/plymouth-debug.log` when starting with the `plymouth:debug` flag.

I'm on a Raspberry Pi model 4B 4GB running Ubuntu 20.04LTS server.

Any help would be appreciated!